# how do i handle uislider's touch event in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, touch, uislider

i want to fire a timer as user slides the slider when the touch ends.
is there a way to handle touch events of uislider?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your slider's `continuous` property is set to `YES`; then use `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` with... `UIControlEventValueChanged`?... in the usual way. The slider should continuously call whatever action method you give it.

Comment: i know this method.i just want to fire timer when user stopped dragging the slider

Comment: Try `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd`, then.

Answer (score 2):

I set the continuous property to NO and kept UIControlEventValueChanged and it manages to only fire off the event when the user releases the slider